# How to use "if" in xslt for character?

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement

I am writing an XSLT code to format Sample.xml(see below)

What I am trying to do is that in my Sample.xslt file,I check for type=mp4 and display the name (in this case the name which should be displayed is **RequiredFileName**. In short, I want that when I apply XSLT to my XML file, I get the name of my MP4 file.

Sample.xml

```
<assets>

<asset id="01" path="//my_computer/path" name="testfile" type="mov">
<child_entries>

<asset id="21" path="//my_computer/test.mp3" name="001-2323" type="mp3"></asset>
<asset id="23" path="//my_computer/test.mp4" name="RequiredFileName" type="mp4"></asset>
<child_entries>

</assets>
```

Sample.xslt

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

    <Path>
<xsl:for-each select="assets"/>
<xsl:if  test="/asset/child_entries/asset/@type = mp4">
<xsl:value-of select="child_entries/asset/@name"/>
</xsl:if>
    </Path>

</xsl:template>
```

Thank you for reading throw it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had several typos in your above xml.  After fixing typos such as non-closed elements, I simply added some extra nested loops.  You can simplify this greatly as I see @lwburk has already shown.  Here is a working stylesheet:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each select="assets">
                <xsl:for-each select="asset">
                    <xsl:for-each select="child_entries">
                        <Path><xsl:value-of select="asset[@type='mp4']/@path" /></Path>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is a working XML input file:

```
<assets>
    <asset id="01" path="//my_computer/path" name="testfile" type="mov">
        <child_entries>
            <asset id="21" path="//my_computer/test.mp3" name="001-2323"
                type="mp3" ></asset>
            <asset id="23" path="//my_computer/test.mp4" name="RequiredFileName"
                type="mp4" ></asset>
        </child_entries>
    </asset>
</assets>
```

These output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Path>//my_computer/test.mp4</Path>
```

I chose path because you had included a Path element.  If you just want the name, you can replace this line in the XSLT file:

```
<Path><xsl:value-of select="asset[@type='mp4']/@path" /></Path>
```

with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="asset[@type='mp4']/@name" />
```

Comment: Wanted to mention that the @lwburk solution is better, just wanted to provide a solution that was closer to "making your code work" for you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You think your question is about `xsl:if` but it's really not. This can be done much more directly. Consider the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Path>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//asset[@type='mp4']/@path"/>
        </Path>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Path>//my_computer/test.mp4</Path>
```

Note that your original input is not well-formed, so instead of making assumptions about how to fix it, I'm using the `descendant-or-self` axis (`//`) to select `asset` elements at any level. There are more efficient solutions if you know exactly where this element will appear in the document.

Let's break the most important piece of this down (`//asset[@type='mp4']/@path`):

- `//asset` selects all `asset` elements in the document (`//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`)
- `[@type='mp4']` filters this list to include only the `asset` elements having an attribute named `type` whose string value is `mp4`
- `/@path` selects the `path` attribute of each of the nodes returned in the previous step

No other nodes are selected and the default templates handle printing the text, so this is really all you need.

Note that this might not print want you want if you have more than one element of this type. You'd end up with something like this:

```
<Path>//my_computer/test.mp3//my_computer/test.mp4</Path>
```

If you want one `Path` element in the output for each matching element in the input, then do something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//asset[@type='mp4']" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="asset">
        <Path>
            <xsl:value-of select="@path" />
        </Path>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As always, more specific outputs depend on the set of possible inputs and your particular taste.

As a closing note, **it's *almost never* necessary to use `xsl:for-each`**. The XSLT processor is *already* traversing the nodes in the document. That's just fundamentally at the core of how XSLT works. It's better to match/select what you want directly.